# checking whether a value of a variables belong to a set bootstrap

Tags: dataframe, subset, julia, bootstrap-4, any

I have an array of integer say

```
theIndex = [ 1 2 6 7 17 2]
```

I have a dataframe with one column dataset[:id] containing integers say

```
dataset = DataFrame(id=[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

I want to select all observations in dataset that belongs to the index. and if they appear twice (or more) in the index, I want to select them twice (or more)

At the moment, I am doing it the dumb way.

```
theIndex = [ 1 2 6 7 17 2]
dataset = DataFrame(id=[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
dataset2 = DataFrame(id=Int64[])
for ii1=1:size(theIndex,2)
    for ii2=1:size(dataset[:id],1)
        any(i->i.==dataset[ii2,:id],theIndex[ii1]) ? 
        push!(dataset2,dataset[ii2,:id]) : nothing
    end
end
```

any more elegant solution?

Comment: dataset[vcat([[j for j in 1:nrow(dataset) if dataset[j, :id] == i] for i in theIndex]...),:]

Comment: or `dataset[vcat(map(i->filter(j->dataset[j,:id]==i, 1:nrow(dataset)), theIndex)...),:]`

Comment: thanks a lot that s more compact/elegant. but quite slow for large dataset. is there any command. that could avoid doing two loops.

Comment: I believe you have to do two loops (explicitly or implicitly) if you want to handle repeated values. If `theIndex` had low cardinality of unique values you could cache the results of the inner loop to avoid going through it many times.

Comment: actually I have just realized you could do a nested comprehension `[j for i in theIndex for j in 1:nrow(dataset) if dataset[j, :id] == i]`

Comment: okay found something a lot faster using Any. `dataset2 = DataFrame(id=Int64[])
@time for ii1=1:size(theIndex,1)
    any(dataset[:id].==theIndex[ii1]) ? append!(dataset2,dataset[dataset[:id].==theIndex[ii1],[:id]]) : nothing
end`

Comment: you're looking for the `findin` function. `indices = findin(id, theIndex)` will give you all the indices in `id` that occur in `theIndex`; you can then do `id[indices]` to retrieve the actual elements. I haven't posted this as an answer because DataFrames seems broken on the latest unstable julia for me to test it ... but if it doesn't work directly you can always just collect the DataFrame to an array anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the question wants to calculate a SQL JOIN between `theIndex` and `dataset`. Unfortunately, this functionality is not fully implemented internally by DataFrames. So here is a quick (and efficient) simulation of a JOIN for this purpose:

```
using DataStructures

sort!(dataset, cols=:id]
j = 1
newvec = Vector{Int}() 
for (val,cnt) in SortedDict(countmap(theIndex))
    while j<=nrow(dataset)
        dataset[j,:id] > val && break
        dataset[j,:id] == val && append!(newvec,fill(j,cnt))
        j += 1
    end
end
dataset2 = dataset[newvec,:]
```

DataStructures package is used for the SortedDict. This implementation is should be more efficient than other multi-loop approaches.

Comment: Dan. Thanks a lot. It is super fast, However, it only works in the particular example I gave you. In my "real" example. newvec does not contain enough values. Some id are repeated only once in the new dataset, some can appear multiple times. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @grandemundo Yeah, forgot one-line which sorts `dataset` (updated the answer with it). It is necessary for the algorithm to work and would probably take the longest chunk of running time.

Answer (score 1):

As per my earlier comment, you're looking for the `findin` function.

```julia
julia> Ind = findin( dataset[:id], theIndex); # return indices of elements in
                                              # dataset[:id] that occur in
                                              # theIndex

julia> dataset[:id][Ind]
4-element DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
```

(or if you wanted your result back in the form of a SubDataFrame / view into your dataset, you could do `SubDataFrame(dataset, Ind)` etc)

**EDIT:** as per comments, to ensure repetitions in `theIndex` are taken into account, the sample for each element needs to be appended separately:

```julia
Ind = []; for i in theIndex; append!(Ind, findin(dataset[:id], i)); end
```

`Ind` can then be used to create an array or SubDataFrame as above.

**EDIT 2**:

```julia
julia> @time dataset2 = DataFrame(id=Int64[])
       for ii1=1:size(theIndex,2)
           for ii2=1:size(dataset[:id],1)
               any(i->i.==dataset[ii2,:id],theIndex[ii1]) && 
               push!(dataset2,dataset[ii2,:id])
           end
       end
  0.000016 seconds (24 allocations: 1.594 KiB)

julia> @time Ind = []; for i in theIndex; append!(Ind, findin(dataset[:id], i)); end
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 240 bytes)
```

<sub>(usual cautionary rant about benchmarking in global scope bla bla)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is fast. The issue is how to handle repeats. How can I tweak  findin so that it returns `[1 1 2 2 2 2]`. In this particular example, 2 appears twice in `theIndex`. In case you are familiar with it, that  is to do re-sample with replacement in a bootstrap procedure.

Comment: hm. I see what you're saying. I can't update my answer right this minute, but you could achieve this by performing `findin` on each element of the index separately, either via a list comprehension or via a `map` operation, and then append the resulting sublists into one. I'll update my answer later when I'm in front of a julia terminal.

Comment: having said that, if you want a _proper_ bootstrapping operation, maybe you should be looking at `sample` instead which does just that given a probability distribution. Can't remember which package that is exactly ... I'll let you know about that as well when I can.

Comment: this one: http://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/sampling.html#Sampling-from-Population-1 (sample with or without replacement from a weighted array, which I think is what you're trying to do)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am actually doing block-bootstrap (sampling block of rows based on a common id) and that does not seem supported there. will think about your suggestion.

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for repetitions in `theIndex`

Comment: thanks but the solution I used in the above comment is faster (at least as far I understand). `dataset2 = DataFrame(id=Int64[]) ;
for ii1=1:size(theIndex,1) 
    any(dataset[:id].==theIndex[ii1]) ? 
    append!(dataset2,dataset[dataset[:id].==theIndex[ii1],[:id]]) : nothing 
end`

Comment: I've added some benchmarks. :)  Mind you, I find julia benchmarks a bit tricky, what with the whole "oh you need to run things twice for the real numbers" business, but, take what you can from it :p